# Keeping Application in sync with Domino calendar

Tags: lotus-domino, interop-domino

We have a application that provides some advanced calendaring features and it talks to any calendaring system like Microsoft Exchange or google calendar.
We are in the process of supporting IBM domino with our application. We are able to create , update and delete meetings through Rest services provided by Domino. We want to be in sync with the calendar items created through other systems also like lotus notes. How do we acheive that? How can we know that a meeting has been created for a user or a conference room through some other calendaring client. Microsoft exchange provides something like subscription and notification. We can subscribe to a user or a room calendar. Any changes in the calendar, the subscriber will get notified. Is there anything equivalent in Domino for similar purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any service built into Domino that provides the equivalent of the Exchange subscription service that you refer to. You could build something using the Notes C API's Extension Manager, but that will require installation of software on the Domino server - which can be a significant obstacle to getting your application adopted.